# Compilation on Linux/Mac but NOT in Windows - C++ with C, C++ and Fortran

Tags: c++, c, linux, windows, fortran

This is a simple, **main C++ program with a C, C++ and a Fortran** function inside.

I am **only able to compile the code on Linux, but not on Windows** however.

The code runs as intended on Linux but **in Windows the program compiles fine but freezes** when the simple Fortran output is shown.

Could you show me what might cause this error?

Each of the C, C++ and Fortran functions simply sets variables a and b to specific values:

ffunction.f:

```
  subroutine ffunction(a,b)
  a=3.0
  b=4.0
  end
```

cfunction1.c:

```
void cfunction1(float *a, float *b) {
    *a=7.0;
    *b=8.0;
}
```

cppfunction1.c:

```
void cppfunction1(float *a, float *b) {
    *a=7.0;
    *b=8.0;
 }
```

cppprogram.C:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

extern "C" {
  void ffunction_(float *a, float *b);
}

extern "C" {
  void cfunction1(float *a, float *b);
}

void cppfunction1(float *a, float *b);

int main() {
  float a=1.0, b=2.0;

  cout << "Before running Fortran function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  ffunction_(&a,&b);

  cout << "After running Fortran function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cout << "Before running C function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cfunction1(&a,&b);

  cout << "After running C function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cout << "Before running C++ function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  cppfunction1(&a,&b);

  cout << "After running C++ function:" << endl;
  cout << "a=" << a << endl;
  cout << "b=" << b << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: never done fortran on windows, but i'd guess calling convention?

Comment: Are you able to compile on windows ? Yes or no ? You said both at the same time...

Comment: What are you using to compile ?

Comment: returning from a subroutine in FORTRAN necessitate both `RETURN` and `END`.

Comment: [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa278672(v=vs.60).aspx) suggests that you might need `__stdcall` when declaring the Fortran function in C/C++.

Comment: @Jean-Baptiste, yes I am able to compile everything on both Windows and Linux using gcc, g++ and gfortran. On Windows the .exe freezes. You can see the files here as well: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gswik0pifq6ov37/AACOTs0pGoTr4ZFV76BrJl_Qa?dl=0

Comment: @Jean-BaptisteYunès -- no, the `return` statement is not required on exit from a subroutine in Fortran.

Comment: If you are using a current (in terms of maintenance and support) Fortran compiler, then you should be using the C-Fortran interoperability features of the Fortran language introduced with Fortran 2003.  On this site see questions tagged fortran-iso-c-binding for more information.